# How can we replace file from Cache folder to an existing folder in android 11 using `MediaStore.createWriteRequest`

Tags: android, mediastore, android-11, scoped-storage

I have to edit a  file, I am copying the file in cache directory editing the file and want to replace the existing file in Android 11, I have come across, `MediaStore.createWriteRequest`

this is the code I am trying

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    public void editSongAPI30(Context context, ArrayList<SongsEntity> arrayList) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        ArrayList<Uri> arrayList2 = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            arrayList2.add(Uri.parse(arrayList.get(i).get_path())); // You need to use the Uri you got using ContentUris.withAppendedId() method
        }
        Collections.addAll(arrayList2);
        IntentSender intentSender = MediaStore.createWriteRequest(contentResolver, arrayList2).getIntentSender();
        IntentSenderRequest senderRequest = new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender)
                .setFillInIntent(null)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION, 0)
                .build();
        editResultLauncher.launch(senderRequest);
    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> editResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, "file Edited.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     
                }
            }
    );
```

where `arrayList.get(i). = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, songCursor.getLong(songCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID))).toString()`

My question is how to copy and overwrite file from `(EditActivity.this.getCacheDir())` to the original file destination using `MediaStore.createWriteRequest`

Comment: `.get_path())); // You need to use the Uri you got using ContentUris.withAppendedId() method` Indeed. but Uri.getPath() is only a part of the Ur. The whole ur is Uri.toString().

Comment: arrayList2.add(arrayList.get(i); // You need to use the Uri you got using ContentUris.withAppendedId() method

Comment: You got the solution or not?

Comment: @blackapps can u please share an working example of it

Comment: I see no source file. And i see no destination uri. I have no idea what you wanna do with a whole list of uries when you want to edit/write ONE file.

Comment: @blackapps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70530249/how-to-replace-file-in-android-11-using-mediastore-createwriterequest

check my question

Comment: Sorry i will not read that post. Write a clear question here that is understandable.